# ¿Como puedo pasarle una consulta a un pivot?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Tengo una pregunta como puedo pasarle una consulta a un pivot en vez pasar datos estáticos en sql server.

Lo que quiero es que en vez de pasar fechas estáticas lo genere mediante una consulta que esta comentado líneas debajo `(select Fecha_Registro FROM Sigeri)`

```
select * from
(
select 
Id_Colaborador,
Nombre_Colaborador,
Id_Unidad_Organizativa,
Fecha_Registro,
Hora_Registro
from Sigeri
)s
pivot(
    max(Hora_Registro)
    for[Fecha_Registro] in --(select Fecha_Registro FROM Sigeri)
([2019-08-01],
[2019-08-02],
[2019-08-05],
[2019-08-06],
[2019-08-07],
[2019-08-08],
[2019-08-09],
[2019-08-12],
[2019-08-13],
[2019-08-14],
[2019-08-15],
[2019-08-16],
[2019-08-19],
[2019-08-20],
[2019-08-21],
[2019-08-22],
[2019-08-23],
[2019-08-26],
[2019-08-27],
[2019-08-28],
[2019-08-29])
)p
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesitas crear la instrucción con código dinámico.

Comment: te agradecería un ejemplo ya que soy nuevo sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo prueba con esto.

```
DECLARE @SQLDynamic NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @SQLDynamic=COALESCE(@SQLDynamic+',','')+'['+CAST(Fecha_Registro    AS nvarchar(20))+']' 
FROM Sigeri  --Obtenemos los registros 
GROUP BY Fecha_Registro    -- POR SI HAY FECHAS REPETIDAS

DECLARE @SQLFULL NVARCHAR(MAX)='

select * from
(
select 
Id_Colaborador,
Nombre_Colaborador,
Id_Unidad_Organizativa,
Fecha_Registro,
Hora_Registro
from Sigeri
)s
pivot(
    max(Hora_Registro)
    for[Fecha_Registro] in --(select Fecha_Registro FROM Sigeri)
('+@SQLDynamic+') --Le pasamos los registros
)p'


EXEC(@SQLFULL)
```

Un pequeño ejemplo, no se si asi sean los datos de tu tabla, pero lo hice de prueba.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2a8c6496ab6ce26d07758b2c5efec288

Saludos, si te marca error o algo ahora lo vemos.